# replace function for special characters

Tags: javascript, replace

I am attempting to use the replace() function on a large amount of text, to filter out "[","{","(", and many other special characters. I initially attempted to just say:

```
replace(/"{"/g," ")
```

But this did not work, I tried a series of variations like this, using:

```
"/{/"g
```

or

```
"/{/g"
```

Yet, none of them worked. I have also tried attaching the first replace parameter to a variable as they do in the [Mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var replacingStuff = /{/g;
str.replace(replacingStuff," ");
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to escape characters with a special meaning in regex with backslashes.

Comment: I am using the backslash to make the replace function global, therefore I cannot remove them.

Comment: Don't say you can't before you didn't try. That's JavaScript basics. `.replace(/\[/g, '')` or multiple chars within brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/[/[]/g` as the regex to get rid of `[`

Basically, if you want to get rid of a certain character, it needs to be in brackets. For example, if you wanted to replace the characters a, b, and c, you would use the regex `/[abc]/g`.

You can use the snippet below. The regex pattern I used was `/[[{(]/g`. It may seem a bit overwhelming, but all it's doing is removing all the characters inside the bracket. Strip away the outside brackets and you get `[{(` which is the characters the regex will replace.

```js
var text = "[fas[ds{ed[d{s(fasd[fa(sd"

console.log(text.replace(/[[{(]/g, ''));
```